# Show firefox addon toolbar on certain URL

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

How do I enable Toolbar (set Hidden to False) when a URL is matching pattern?

I know the logic for this (if url == "...") elemById("toolbar").setAttrib(hidden, false), but I don't know how can I run this javascript on (for example) every tab change.

Or maybe you can suggest different (better) way (event)?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://testtoolbar/skin/testtoolbar.css" type="text/css"?>
<overlay id="PDM-Overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://testtoolbar/content/testtoolbar.js" />     
    <toolbox id="navigator-toolbox">
        <toolbar id="PDM-Toolbar" toolbarname="PDM Toolbar" accesskey="T" class="chromeclass-toolbar" 
        context="toolbar-context-menu" hidden="false" persist="hidden">
            <textbox id="testreference" value="" type="timed" oncommand="gotoitem(event)"/>
            <button id="GoButton" label="Go to Item" oncommand="gotoitem(event)"/>
        </toolbar>
    </toolbox>
</overlay>
```

Comment: You did added `xul` tag but to be sure, can you add to question, if it is a xul-based, bootstraped or jpm extension?

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle two cases:

1. When user selects a tab. See [Detecting Tab Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_tab_selection)
2. When a new URL is loaded in an existing tab (e.g user clicked on a link that loaded a new url, or user typed in a new url in address bar).

   See [Listening to events on all tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Listening_to_events_on_all_tabs). I think `onLocationChanged` is the event that would help you in this case.